# Issue in taking character input to C program

Tags: c, function, scanf, eof, abort

I am trying to run a program that check one input character from user when they enter either `M`, `F` or `N`. It will check and compare char character. but when I run the program. It doesn't work. I have try many medhod with my friends and we can't figure this out. The program can't valid data that user enter. Some help please.

```
typedef struct {
    char onePatient.gender;
}PATIENT_T

PATIENT_T onePatient;
```

is a `typedef` already declared on the top, sorry for that.

This is program function:

```
void checkGender(char pointerGender)
{
char gender;
char buffer[32];
char word_M = ('M'); /* Male */
char word_F = ('F'); /* Female */
char word_N = ('N'); /* None */

printf("\nEnter Gender: ");
fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin);
//strcpy(&gender,buffer);
sscanf(buffer,"%c",&gender);

while((strcasecmp(&gender,&word_M) != 0)||(strcasecmp(&gender,&word_M) != 0)||(strcasecmp(&gender,&word_N) != 0))
{
    printf("\nError: Invalidate Grade");
    printf("\n(Please enter wheather M [for Male], F [for Female] or N [for None])");
    printf("\nEnter gender: ");
    fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin);
    //strcpy(&gender,buffer);
    sscanf(buffer,"%c",&gender);
}

}
```

This is in main function:

```
int main()
{
    char pointerGender;

    PATIENT_T onePatient;

    checkGender(pointerGender);
    strcpy(&onePatient.gender,&pointerGender);

    printf("\n%s",&onePatient.gender);
}
```

Terminal show:

```
192:iHeal Hospital iFluke$ gcc -o checkFormat_Fluke checkFormat_Fluke.c
192:iHeal Hospital iFluke$ ./checkFormat_Fluke

Enter Name: fluke

Enter Gender: M

Error: Invalidate Grade
(Please enter wheather M [for Male], F [for Female] or N [for None])
Enter gender: F

Error: Invalidate Grade
(Please enter wheather M [for Male], F [for Female] or N [for None])
Enter gender: N

Error: Invalidate Grade
(Please enter wheather M [for Male], F [for Female] or N [for None])
Enter gender:
```

Comment: Also, the declaration for onePatient is missing.

Comment: PATIENT_T onePatient;
is a TypeDef already declare on the top, sorry for that.

Comment: And what´s PATIENT_T (again)? ... Well, strcpy for strings, chars, and class objects. Unlikely that this is ok. => The whole code looks like nonsense.

Comment: compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: Btw., `PATIENT_T onePatient;` is not a typedef, but a normal instance.

Comment: Sorry to say that, but the now added typedef looks like nonsense too (and another edit now didn´t help. Stop editing, sit down and read a C++ book)

Comment: @deviantfan , How would a C++ book provide help for a C Program?

Comment: Well, then a C book. The typedef, the strcpy usage and more things are invalid in both languages.

Comment: I think that the problem is that `||` should be changed into `&&`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `strcasecmp` to compare characters. It's not completely wrong, but a single character is not a properly terminated string.

If you must do comparison this way, use `strncasecmp`:

```
if(strncasecmp(&gender,&word_M, 1) == 0)
```

That will limit it to comparing one character.

Also, your retry loop doesn't check for 'F', but checks 'M' twice.

Answer (score 0):

Since your input is only a single char, why have you declared buffer[32] ?

Use something like

```
char input;
scanf("%c" &input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code. I think, it solves your purpose, minus the complexity.

Note:

1. `EOF` is achieved by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>
2. This code is case insensitive [`M` and `m` denotes same thing].

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char userInput;

    printf("Enter the Gender ( M [for Male], F [for Female] or N [for None] )\n");
    while ( scanf (" %c", &userInput) != EOF )
    {
    switch (userInput)
    {
        case 'M':
        case 'm':
                    printf("Male\n");
                    break;

        case 'F':
        case 'f':
                    printf("Female\n");
                    break;

        case 'N':
        case 'n':
                    printf("None\n");
                    break;

        default:
                printf("Wrong value !!!\n");
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Sourav you are not helping the students by giving them complete code!!

Comment: @Manav kindly explain your comment.

Comment: The fundamental problem with homework questions is that if you hand someone a cut-and-paste answer to a homework question, they won't learn anything, but it's very difficult to write an answer that will teach the poster something but will also be useful to future readers. Quoted from http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255477/please-clarify-the-policy-on-homework-questions

Comment: @Manav before reading the linked answer, read the question. it says, in  the targeted post [now removed], `There's no attempt at a solution, just a bare-bones statement of the problem.` In this Q, OP posted his/her code, i/p - o/p and has shown some effort. This does not exactly qualify for `Homework` question tag.

Comment: `homework` tag has been officially deprecated. Check http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions . I feel `a Programmer's mind is not a vessel to be filled with code, rather it's a fire to be ignited`.

Comment: @Manav there were multiple issues with the original code. instead I provided an alternate and simplistic approach, which , IMO, required a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I appreciate you effort and intention, however, please look in the larger scheme of things on this forum.

Comment: @Manav will try my best. also, thanks to you for providing the inputs. at times, we all need some evaluation. :-)